# passing a list of derived objects to a function that expects to get a list of base objects

Tags: c++, polymorphism

```
Base{
public:
    Base(int i);
    virtual void doSomething(int z);
}
Derived:public Base{
public:
    Derived(int j);   
}
void myFunc(list<Base> myList,int y){
        for(list<Base>::iterator it = myList.begin();it!=myList.end();++it){
            it->doSomething(y);
        }
    }
main(){

    list<Derived> dList;
    myFunc(dList)
}
```

I can't seem to pass a list of Derived instead of base. I understand that it can be problematic to do this since than one could add different derived types to the list but I only want to change the objects on the list, not add any more objects. I tried playing around with const but that still did not help.I can't use the for_each function since do something gets an argument.
Any ideas?

Comment: why not pass a `list<Base>` that is filled with `Derived` objects ?

Comment: This is *obviously* not your real code.

Comment: If `Derived` instances can be passed instead of `Base` ones, `list<Derived>` and `list<Base>` are two completely different types though.

Comment: The simpler way would be to use template.

Comment: @JBL I have 2 types of derived and i want  to use a function defined in base on a list of both types of derived

Comment: `std::list<Base>` and `std::list<Derived>` are two different types entirely. Just because their value types are derivations means nothing (and you're eventually setting yourself up for a helluva [slicing problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing) if you continue down this road). Nor is there any polymorphism in this. To do that right you need pointers or references to your objects; you have neither.

Comment: @WhozCraig I also tried using pointers (i.e list<Derived*>) but visual studio tells me that it can't convert between list<Derived*> to list<Base*>

Comment: @user3872358 that's because the original storage of your `Derived*` pointer list should have been `Base*` in the first place. And in doing so smart pointers are generally whats for dinner. [See example](http://ideone.com/wma2BR)

Answer (score 1):

> I have 2 types of derived and i want to be to use a function defined in base on a list of both types of derived

Then use a template:

```
template<typename T>
void myFunc(list<T> myList, int y) {
    for(typename list<T>::iterator it = myList.begin(); it!=myList.end(); ++it){
        it->doSomething(y);
        //use any function present in Base
    }
}
```

This function will accept any `list` of any instance of type `Base` or any of its derived classes.

You can't force the compiler to use polymorphism to accept a `list<T>` where it expects a `list<U>`, whatever `T` and `U` are, because these will always be unrelated polymorphically-wise.

Comment: is there any way of forcing the compiler to to accept list<T*> if it accepts list<U*> assuming T is derived from U?

Comment: @user3872358 No. Not without templates. **These are different, polymorphically unrelated types**

Comment: And you'd need a `typename` there too. Or just `auto`.

Comment: To be clear, this will accept any `std::list<>` of **any type** that exposes a member called `doSomething` that takes an `int` argument. Neither `Base` nor `Derived` have anything to do with it, save for they fulfill that requirement. So too would `SomeClass` if it had a member `Type doSomething(int)`.

Comment: There are ways to force `T` to derive from `U` with SFINAE or `static_assert`.

Comment: Yep, C++11's [std::is_base_of](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of) could be used for that.